# IIS returns different USERNAME than debug

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, environment-variables, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C# web application that calls `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")`. When debugging it returns the username I am signed in to the machine as it should.

I then set up my site in IIS. The site runs Anonymous and Forms Authentication. The site also runs on DefaultAppPool, but the identity is a service account that has proper access to the DB. When I hit a page that has `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")` the returned value is the name of the server. The returned value is neither the AD user I am logged in as nor the service account. Why is it pulling the server name as the USERNAME?

Comment: Can you provide more information about why you are trying to get this information? Are you trying to get the username of the currently logged in user?

Comment: @kettch the user logged in to AD yes, the user logged into the application no. Because the GetEnvironmentVariable call is wrapped around the application before they use forms authentication to log in to the application.

Comment: Just a guess, but when you configure an application pool you can choose to load a profile for the identity, or not. Maybe if you choose not to load a profile the default value is the server name.

Comment: @Crowcoder But I AM loading a profile. I'm using a service account that has certain permissions to the DB

Comment: Please learn what is application pool identity and log in users. What you observed is perfectly normal, but you just not yet know the correct way to understand the concepts.

Comment: @LexLi I don't need log in users. The line of code is in the Site.master page so it looks for that environment variable well before a user logs in. I don't even need the application pool identity, that is just a service account for the DB. I need the account I am logged on to the machine as.

Comment: "The account I am logged on to the machine as" is an invalid concept when your app is hosted on IIS. You need to understand the facts that IIS can run and host your web apps when you are not even logged on to the machine. Thus, that's how a typical service runs. Read more, and don't use "I need" and "I don't need" as excuse.

Comment: @LexLi I understand IIS can run while I'm not logged on. But say the web app is on serverondomain1 so John Smith logs on to his machine using his AD account jsmith. Now I know the web app is running as the service account I set in the app pool, but how do I get jsmith?

Comment: `Page.User` or `Controller.User`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @LexLi That was it! Thank you Lex Li

Comment: @toadfromgrove If you've found the solution, please post it as answer which will help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LexLi provided the line of code needed to pull the Windows context the user's browser is hitting the website with. Page.User